# Errors in defining typedef in C

Tags: c, gcc, typedef

I'm trying to define a cache in C, I first define the following

```
typedef unsigned int32_t mem_address;

typedef struct {
int val;
mem_address tag;
} block;


typedef struct {
block *array_of_blocks;
} cache_whole;
```

and then initialise a new cache in the last line of code.

```
cache_whole cache;
```

However, my compiler throws out these errors.

Lines 135, 137, 138 etc refer to code of the form `cache.array_of_blocks`, lines 12-43 are the ones shown.

Ignore the instruction_cache and data_cache as they are defined in the exact same way as the cache shown in the last line of the code, hence the errors are the same. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. [image]

Comment: Try `uint32_t` instead of `unsigned int32_t`.

Comment: **Do not post images unnecessarily.** Post text.

Comment: this line: `typedef unsigned int32_t mem_address;` contains a conflict.  Suggest: `typedef uint32_t mem_address;`

Comment: If the posted code is correct, then `cache` should be defined.  Since the compiler says it is not defined, we need the actual code.  Please post the actual code.

Answer (score 2):

`typedef` can handle only one type at time,
here you have two types `unsigned` and `int32_t`,
you can not write something like `unsinged int32_t`, `unsigned/signed` works
only with `char`, `short`, `int` and `long`.
so right line would be

```
typedef unt32_t mem_address;
```

Comment: This fixed it, I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed to.